# Need help figuring this type of problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does anyone know what is the name/type of the following problem:

[image]

And the sequence continues

Comment: Fractals.  IFS.  Mandelbrot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like an L-system, represented by turtle graphics. Using the same notation as in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system), your specific case could be written in this way:

- **Variables**: F
- **Constants**: +, −
- **Start**: +F−F−F+
- **Rules**: (F $\rightarrow$ F+F−F−F+F)

You get a sequence of strings over the alphabet {F, +, −} in the following way. The first element $s_0$ of the sequence is the start string. For each $n$, the $n$-th element $s_n$ of the sequence is obtained from $s_{n-1}$ by substituting all the instances of the variable F with another string according to the rule above.

Then, in order to draw the picture of a string $s_n$, suppose that you have a cursor pointing to the right. Read the characters of the string one by one, and according to the character you're reading do the following actions:

- F means "draw a straight line (of fixed length) forward", in the direction the cursor is pointing;
- + means "turn the cursor left 90° (anticlockwise)";
- − means "turn the cursor right 90° (clockwise)".

Notice that the picture you get with this L-system is a slight variation of the Koch curve with 90° angles given as an example in the article above (the rule is exactly the same). If you could hypothetically pass to the limit of the sequence, whatever this means, you would get a fractal.